# How to read an interpret an integer from a String as the same?

Tags: java, numbers, bufferedreader

I am reading a file with a list of strings and integers. The file looks something as shown below:

File.txt

This is 1234
 This is 2568

I want to subtract the numbers from two consecutive lines with each other. I am reading the lines in using the BufferedReader operation. I store the strings into an array list and wish to subtract the numbers I find in the string with each other. However I cant figure out a way to subtract them. 
The code so far looks something like this

```
 ArrayList<String> string =new ArrayList<>();
 reading =new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\User1\\File.txt");

 while( (presentString=read.readLine())!=null){
      string.add(presentString );
 }
```

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: `presentString==reading.readLine()!=null`?

Comment: @TheCoffeeKid : Sorry for the typo :)

Comment: Try `System.out.println(whatYouAreTryingToAdd)` and comment the output.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of your question, you want to subtract the numbers in consecutive strings and then replace the original string with the `result`. This code should do that:

```
ArrayList<String> strings =new ArrayList<>();
BufferedReader reading =new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\User1\\File.txt");
String presentString = "";
while( (presentString==read.readLine())!=null){
    strings.add(presentString);
}
for(int i=0;i<strings.size();i+=2){
    //split the string so that the number is the last string in the array
    String[] list1 = strings.get(i).split(" ");
    String[] list2 = strings.get(i+1).split(" ");

    //subtract the after parsing the strings
    int result = Integer.parseInt(list2[list2.length-1]) - Integer.parseInt(list1[list1.length-1]);
    System.out.println(list2[list2.length-1] + "-" + list1[list1.length-1] + "=" + result);

    //remove the second string and replace the string with the result
    strings.remove(i+1);
    strings.add(i+1,"This is "+result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.util.regex.Matcher` and a regular expression matching only numbers.
I've modified your code, now it fills the array `numbers` with all numbers found in a file, then you can do whatever you want with them:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
BufferedReader reading = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\User1\\File.txt");

//pattern that matches any number of digits from 0 to 9
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+"); 

while((presentString = read.readLine()) != null) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(presentString);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String numberAsString = matcher.group();
        numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(numberAsString));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have a file called "File.txt", and you want to parse the two integers inside of it? Assuming the only things that change are the numbers, you can do the following:

```
public int getSubtractedIntegersFromFile(File file){
    try {
        String filecontents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.toURI())));
        String s1;
        int int1 = Integer.parseInt((s1 = filecontents.substring(8, filecontents.length())));
        int int2 = Integer.parseInt(filecontents.substring(17 + s1.length(), filecontents.length()));
        return int2 - int1;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```